# Get files modified/added/removed from a commit in LibGit2Sharp

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I've this method, where I get files from my last commit:

```
static void GetFiles(Tree t, String dir = "")
{
    foreach (TreeEntry treeEntry in t)
    {
        if (treeEntry.TargetType == TreeEntryTargetType.Tree)
        {
            Tree tr = repo.Lookup<Tree>(treeEntry.Target.Sha);
            GetFiles(tr, dir + "/" + treeEntry.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            string caminho = dir + "/" + treeEntry.Path;
            arquivos.Add(caminho);
        }
        
    }
    return;
}
```

I did a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133684/get-changes-between-a-commit-and-its-parent-with-libgit2sharp), but I'm newbie with C# and don't understand.

I have this repository:

```
c:/teste
| - octocat.txt
| - parentoctocat.txt
| - /outros
| | - octocatblue.txt
| | - octored.txt
```

My last commit have this files modified:

```
c:/teste
| - /outros
| | - octocatblue.txt <- This modified
| | - octored.txt <- This new
```

With my method `GetFiles` I've all files like in this print. How get only the modified/added/removed files?

[image: Program execution]

---

**How can I get the previous commit and compare getting the  tree of difference?**

---

## Solution

```
static void CompareTrees()
{
    using (repo)
    {
        Tree commitTree = repo.Head.Tip.Tree; // Main Tree
        Tree parentCommitTree = repo.Head.Tip.Parents.First().Tree; // Secondary Tree

        var patch = repo.Diff.Compare<Patch>(parentCommitTree, commitTree); // Difference

        foreach (var ptc in patch)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ptc.Status +" -> "+ptc.Path); // Status -> File Path
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of how git store data in the file systems, a git commit is a snapshot of all the files contained in the commit. Then the `Tree` object return you the state of all the files of the repository.

I think that you must do the diff between the tree of this commit and the tree of the previous one and I think it should be done with the method `Repository.Diff.Compare()`

Comment: Can you help me change my method `GetFiles` for do this?