# How to list files(added/modified/removed etc) in a git commit(sha) using libgi2Sharp?

Tags: c#, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

what is the equivalent of `git show --name-only <commit>`in libgit2sharp? i have a list of `sha` and want to all files changed as a part of that commit.
This question didnt work for me.. [How to get files changed/removed/added using libgit2sharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750641/how-to-get-files-changed-removed-added-using-libgit2sharp)

Comment: What didn't work about the other question?

Comment: Also wondering why that answer "does not work"? http://stackoverflow.com/a/33758609/4984832

Comment: Ahhh, I think I understand what the mis-understanding is... using your git cmd example with only one <commit> is fine if that commit only has one parent and thus a single path DAG with only two nodes, but try it on a merge commit and you will see no changes as what is it going to compare too? But changes did occur if you compare it to the merge parent, thus you need two "commits".

Comment: Here is the scenario I have : (12/02/2015 : SayHello/hello.js modified :commit 1234) (12/03/2015 : SayHello/hello.js modified, SayHello/hello2.js modified :commit 5678). I run this code snippet and I can only see SayHello/hello.js modified. @RobertN can you please explain how to solve this?

Comment: In that example, if you `git log --name-only 1234..5678` do you not get both files?